# How to get Current Year and Previous Year values as Columns

Tags: sql-server

Can any body please tell me about below case.

I have fact table which has datekey, I have bridge table which has `Datekey` and `PYdatekey`( PYDatekey represents last year value).

When I want current year value, I am joining with `FactTable.DateKey = BridgeTable.DateKey`, for Last year values `FactTable.DateKey=BridgeTable.PYDateKey`.

I am writing two separate queries doing union all to get these values as rows.

But now I need to get these values as columns. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` - [Using Inner Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: rather than describe, just post table structure with entry with desired output structure. Also show,  still what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to FactTable twice to get the previous and current data separately.

Use LEFT JOIN in case Datekey and/or PYdatekey is not required in BridgeTable.

```
--Sample data
CREATE TABLE BridgeTable (Datekey int, PYdatekey int)
CREATE TABLE FactTable (datekey int, SomeField varchar(100))
INSERT INTO FactTable VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO FactTable VALUES (2, 'B')
INSERT INTO BridgeTable VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO BridgeTable VALUES (1, null)
INSERT INTO BridgeTable VALUES (null, 2)

--Query
SELECT PreviousFacts.SomeField AS Previous_SomeField, CurrentFacts.SomeField AS Current_SomeField --Or whatever columns you need
FROM BridgeTable
LEFT JOIN FactTable PreviousFacts ON BridgeTable.PYdatekey = PreviousFacts.DateKey
LEFT JOIN FactTable CurrentFacts ON BridgeTable.Datekey = CurrentFacts.DateKey
```